# React Native version mismatch error even when both are of same version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Using ignite boilerplate with expo for my react-native project. I am very new to this , hence facing so many issues. One such issue is **React Native version mismatch**.

```
Javascript Version : 0.54.2
Native Version : 0.52.0
```

I am sure i have updated the native version to 0.54.2 using this command : `npm install  react-native@0.54.2` . I checked in the package.json also to confirm the same. But when launching the I still see the same error.

Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try `react-native upgrade 0.54.2 --legacy true`